# Printing a multi-page HTML5 canvas element

Tags: image, html5-canvas, printing-web-page, multipage

This is the first question I've ever asked on here, as normally I can find an answer that will solve all my problems. However, this week I've hit quite the wall.

I'm using a canvas on my page that's working great and can be saved as an image file. I've also created a button that will open the canvas in a new window for printing after using toDataURL. I'm using the code below:

```
function printable() {
    var dataUrl = document.getElementById("mainCanvas").toDataURL("image/png");
    var windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
    windowContent += '<head><title>Print Map</title></head>';
    windowContent += '<body>';
    windowContent += '<img src = "' + dataUrl + '">';
    windowContent += '</body>';
    windowContent += '</html>';
    var printWin = window.open('', '', width = 340, height = 260);
    printWin.document.open();
    printWin.document.write(windowContent);
    printWin.document.close();
    printWin.focus();
    printWin.print();
}
```

This works great and opens the print dialogue to print my canvas image. My issue is that my image is larger than a single page and only the first page of my image prints. Is there any way to print my canvas across multiple pages, or should i just chalk this up to bad browser to printer functionality and get my users who need to print to use a different program after saving their canvas locally?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is a stupid solution, but definitely work.

use a script to split canvas, and put contents to several separate canvases.

use these functions:

```
ImageData getImageData(in float x, in float y, in float width, in float height);
void putImageData(in ImageData imagedata, in float dx, double dy, in float dirtyX Optional , in float dirtyY Optional , in float dirtyWidth Optional , in float dirtyHeight Optional );
```